# What is the default value when create multi dimention c# array

Tags: c#

In normal situation ,I can create an array like this:

```
int [,] arr =new int[2,2];
```

But if I use:

```
int[,] arr= new int[2];
```

What is the default value for the second parameter? 0 or 1 or null?

Comment: What happens when you *compile* the code?

Comment: Have you even tried that? It won't compile. `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'int[*,*]`.

Comment: This won't compile. Your question makes no sense if you haven't checked that it can even compile

Comment: The answer, however, is 1, if there is an answer at all.  And this holds true no matter how many additional "default" dimensions you attempt to declare.

Comment: @hoodaticus Care to write a program that demonstrates that fact?

Comment: @Servy I'd prefer common sense based on the number of elements contained in a 2 element array versus a 2 x 1 versus a 2 x 1 x 1 versus a 2 x 1 x 1 x 1.

Comment: @hoodaticus Since you feel that common sense tells you that that's what the answer is, I'm sure you'll have no problem writing up a simple program that proves it to be true.  After all, you can just create an array without specifying a dimension and print out the length of the unspecified dimension.  It's only a few lines of code.

Comment: @Servy, some of us have experience in more than one language, including those in which the dimensionality of a contiguous data structure is a point of view, not some pedantic return value of a reflection interface.  Also, I said "if there is an answer at all".  Obviously you choose to believe there isn't one, so your ish is misplaced.

Comment: @hoodaticus I'm sure plenty of other language will behave differently than C# in this regard.  That doesn't change the answer to what the behavior of C# is in this regard.  That some other language defaults the size of a dimension not specified in a particular way doesn't change how C# handles it.  I gave you one suggestion of how you could prove your point; if you'd prefer to not use reflection (not that I suggested using reflection, by the way, I merely suggested calling a property on the object that tells you its length), feel free to demo your answer some other way.

Comment: The question is, *"If I use: `int[,] arr = new int[2];` What is the default value for the second parameter"*. The answer is, "There is no default value for the second parameter; that's an illegal statement and it won't compile."

Comment: void Main()
{
 DimensionsAreHardYo.Test();
}

unsafe static class DimensionsAreHardYo
{
 public static void Test()
 {
  int[,] dimensions_are_illusions = new int[2,2];
  dimensions_are_illusions[1,1] = 42;
  fixed (int* pArray = &dimensions_are_illusions[0,0])
  {
   Debug.Print(pArray[3].ToString());
  }
 }
}   // TL;DR: C# does not have some magical property that excludes it from math, logic, and reason.

Comment: @Rufus - all I was ever saying to cause so much upset was that IF (please google that word if it's confusing) there were a default value, that default would be 1.

Comment: @hoodaticus, perhaps explain for the simple minded among us (myself included) how writing code that supplies the second dimension's value proves that it would be 1 if omitted? (The reality is that C# doesn't allow you to omit the value for this kind of array, so making an argument over the default is fruitless.) (The other reality is that the asker made no attempt to even compile his own code, which makes this entire question pointless.)

Comment: First, you should chill with the insulting comments, @hoodaticus. But that seems a lot like saying "**IF** you could cast the string `"A"` to an `int`, the value would be `65`". Because in both cases, **you can't do that**. The contents of your "if" block are irrelevant because the condition evaluates to false.

Comment: @RufusL - And yet, I just wrote a demo program (above) that accesses a 2d array using 1d syntax in C#.

Comment: @hoodaticus And yet, your example did not include the line: `int[,] arr = new int[2];`

Comment: I'm exiting this conversation because "if" is apparently not processing here.

Comment: @hoodaticus Indeed, you successfully demonstrated that you can treat a 2D array as if it were a 1D array, using unsafe code, (because all multi-dimensional arrays are implemented, under the hood, as one dimensional arrays, and the mult-dimensional values are simply converted into a single index under the hood when a location is accessed).  It *doesn't* show how you can create an array without specifying the value for a given dimension, and that that value is 1 in such a situation.

Comment: @Servy - I have never disagreed with you on that.  In fact, despite all our heated conversations over the months, I'm not sure I've ever in substance disagreed with you at all xD.  Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

The code you propose will not compile. You're instantiating an orange to an apple. Your first bit of code works fine however, and it defaults to zero in all dimensions.

[image: Image of all four array elements defaulting to zero.]